# Range Reference Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I working some VBA to copy cells to another worksheet in the same workbook. However I am running into an error. Here is the challenege:

1. Worksheet with data to be searched.
2. I am looping through cells in Column A and looking for the word Properties: If the words is found I want to copy and paste special(transpose) the values in the adjacent cells up to three rows down to another worksheet in the same workbook.
   So for example if the word "Properties is found in cell A9 I need to copy the values in B10:B12 and paste special transpose to the next empty row on Metadata Worksheet.
3. I got it working to copy the cell Offset(1,1), however I am having difficult expanding the copy range. Please see code below. The commented out code works fine, but the line just below it is what i am trying but it wont work.

   ```
   Private Sub Search_n_Copy()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, srchRng As Range
   Dim strSearch As String
   Dim QueryResults As Worksheet
   Set QueryResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
   QueryResults.Name = "MetaData"
   strSearch = "Properties"
   Dim LastRow As Long


   With QueryResults
   QueryResults.Range("A1").Value = "SI_ID"
   QueryResults.Range("B1").Value = "SI_NAME"
   QueryResults.Range("C1").Value = "SI_WEBI_DOC_PROPERTIES"
   End With


   With ws
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
   Set srchRng = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
   For Each aCell In srchRng
    If aCell.Value = "Properties" Then
    ''aCell.Offset(1, 1).Copy
    .Range("aCell.Offset(1, 1):aCell.Offset(3,1)").Copy
     QueryResults.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
       False, Transpose:=True
    End If
    Next aCell
   End With
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: `.Range(aCell.Offset(1, 1),aCell.Offset(3,1)).Copy`

Comment: `aCell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(rowsize:=3).Copy`